# Vuejs: Can't pass object to web component using v-bind

Tags: javascript, angular, vue.js, web-component

I have a web component built with Stencil that I imported into a Vue  project. The component takes in an object as a prop. When I pass the object using `v-bind`, it doesn't work. When I pass it using `ref` in JavaScript, then it works.

For example, this does not set my property:

```html
<my-web-component :my-object="myObject" />
```

But this does:

```html
<template>
  <my-web-component ref="myObjectRef" />
</template>
<script>
export default {
  //...
  mounted() {
   this.$refs.myObjectRef.myObject = myObject // <-- this works
  }
}
</script>
```

When I use the web component in Angular, it works using `@Input` as usual.

What's the reason that the prop works in Angular, but in Vue I have to assign it in JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`v-bind` assumes an attribute if it can't determine that the target is a property, which would be the case for Stencil components. You'll notice the attribute bound as a generic string (i.e., `[object Object]`) in the DOM when inspecting the component:

[image: screenshot of inspection]

To bind to the Stencil component's property in a Vue 2 template, use `v-bind`'s [`.prop`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) modifier:

```html
<my-web-component :my-object.prop="myObject" />
                            ^^^^^
```

Alternatively, use `v-bind`'s object syntax (works in Vue 2 and Vue 3):

```html
<my-web-component v-bind="{ myObject }" />
```

[Vue 3 demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/binding-object-prop-to-stencil-component-in-vue-3-iwi8t?file=/src/App.vue:76-146)